# Check for user-agent then show only specified contents in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, user-agent

I have a Wordpress website and want to show a specified content to a user who have a specified User-agent. Here is what I've done:

```
<?php
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
if (strpos( $user_agent, 'CostumizedAgent') !== false)
{
echo "<html><body>Show Only this codes</body></html>
}
else
{
// Show normal website
}
?>
```

In the condition where user agent doesn't contain `CostumizedAgent` word, normal website will be shown to the user (a normal wordpress website) but if contains word `CostumizedAgent` it'll only echo a specified HTML code to the user. I use this to create a simple secretly content! (I know it's no the way it should be done :D)

So, what should I do? Which codes I have to put in `else` place? Where should I put all the codes to work? (on all pages of website)

Answer (score 6):

The better way to do that is to create a separate theme for your other user agent. Assuming you want to create a mobile version of your website, this is what you'll have to put in the `functions.php` of your desktop (default) theme :

```
function change_theme($current_theme) {
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    if(strpos( $user_agent, 'CostumizedAgent') !== false) {
        return 'mobile-theme';
    } else {
        return $current_theme;
    }
}
add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'change_theme' );
add_filter( 'template', 'change_theme' );
```

This will programmaticaly change the theme based on the user agent, and tell Wordpress to use the `mobile-theme` theme if the user agent condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you. but isn't there any easier method? because I don't want to make a new theme nor install one. I just want to show a single HTML code!

Comment: Well if you want that all the content being replaced by your line, it seems to me to be the best method. Creating a new theme take few minutes only, but if you want you can also edit your header.php, put your condition at the start and exit after you displayed your line for mobile.